# 'PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist' while persisting/merging entity with relations

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm failing while saving my `Schedule` entity with `ScheduleItems`s relation.

I want the following to work:

1. Raw data come from the client in JSON format.
2. Then it is unmarshaled to `Schedule` entity in the controller.
3. Then I pass the `Schedule` to `ScheduleService.save` method which insert/update `Schedule` and related `ScheduleItem`s in DB.

My entity classes look as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Schedule {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Column(name = "SCHEDULE_DATE")
private LocalDate date;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "SHOP_ID")
private Shop shop;
@Version
private int version;
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "schedule", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<ScheduleItem> items = new HashSet<>();
.....
}

@Entity
@IdClass(ScheduleItemId.class)
public class ScheduleItem {
@JsonBackReference
@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "SCHEDULE_ID")
private Schedule schedule;
@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
private Employee employee;
private int startTime;
private int duration;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "WORK_TYPE")
private WorkType type;
......
}

@Entity
public class Employee {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
private String lastName;
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne
private Shop shop;
@ManyToOne
private Position position;
private boolean active = true;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private EmploymentType employment;
......
}
```

I've read a lot of related topics and StackOverflow questions and I still having some questions:

1. Entity passed in service `save` method is detached. In order to save it I have to PERSIST it (in case there is a new `Schedule`) or MERGE (in case there is existing `Schedule`)?
2. I have to manually set both sides of relations with MANAGED entities. So first I persist/merge `Schedule`-> then iterate throught `ScheduleItem`s and set `Schedule` and `Employee` relations -> then I persist/merge `ScheduleItem`s?

My service save method is following:

```
    @Transactional
    public Schedule saveOrUpdate(Schedule schedule) {
    final Schedule managedSchedule = em.merge(schedule);    <----ERROR
    List<ScheduleItem> managedItems = schedule.getItems().stream()
            .map(item -> {
                item.setSchedule(managedSchedule);
                item.setEmployee(em.find(Employee.class, item.getEmployee().getId()));
                return em.merge(item);
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    managedSchedule.setItems(managedItems);
    return managedSchedule;
}
```

When I try to save schedule I get **detached entity passed to persist: com.xxx.employee.Employee;**. But why? I have no cascade property set in any entity.

If I set `cascade=ALL` on `Set<ScheduleItems> items` in `Schedule` I get same error.

The test method that triggers `ScheduleService.saveOrUpdate` method:

```
    @Test
public void saveNonExistingScheduleShouldCreateNewScheduleTest() {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2016, 3, 8);
    Long shopId = 1L;

    Shop shop = shopService.find(shopId);
    Schedule schedule = new Schedule(shop, date);
    Set<ScheduleItem> items = new HashSet<>();
    items.add(new ScheduleItem(schedule, employeeRepository.findOne(1L), 100, 200, WorkType.WORK));
    items.add(new ScheduleItem(schedule, employeeRepository.findOne(2L), 100, 200, WorkType.WORK));
    items.add(new ScheduleItem(schedule, employeeRepository.findOne(3L), 100, 200, WorkType.WORK));
    schedule.setItems(items);

    service.saveOrUpdate(schedule);
}
```

Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't posted how you populate `schedule` object. The information you posted is not enough to analyze the problem.

Comment: @ujulu I edited post to show how `schedule` is populated. It seems like `MERGE` operation propagated from `ScheduleItem` to `Employee`.